# Create new rows according to the values stored in a column

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data

```
structure(list(State = c(56L, 81L, 126L, 161L, 120L, 138L, 71L, 
133L, 6L, 171L, 42L, 64L, 28L, 76L, 56L, 117L, 47L, 69L, 65L, 
105L, 175L, 151L, 0L, 91L, 150L, 157L, 172L, 69L, 132L, 39L, 
152L, 107L, 142L, 174L, 187L, 84L, 58L, 73L, 198L, 5L, 43L, 189L, 
34L, 177L, 119L, 69L, 152L, 155L, 44L, 59L, 20L, 120L, 1L, 173L, 
190L, 121L, 118L, 168L, 80L, 45L, 26L, 15L, 190L, 25L, 7L, 146L, 
177L, 41L, 28L, 190L, 64L, 76L, 194L, 13L, 172L, 120L, 132L, 
160L, 58L, 12L), AgentID = 1:80, t_IDs = c("1 15", "2", "3", 
"4", "5 52 76", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12 71", "13 69", 
"14 72", "1 15", "16", "17", "18 28 46", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "24", "25", "26", "27 75", "18 28 46", "29 77", "30", "31 47", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37 79", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
"42", "43", "44 67", "45", "18 28 46", "31 47", "48", "49", "50", 
"51", "5 52 76", "53", "54", "55 63 70", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "55 63 70", "64", "65", "66", "44 67", "68", 
"13 69", "55 63 70", "12 71", "14 72", "73", "74", "27 75", "5 52 76", 
"29 77", "78", "37 79", "80")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x560df68bf760>)
```

What I want to create turn `t_IDs` column into a new column `IDs` such that there will a new row for containing the values in `t_IDs`.

For example, for such rows

[image]

the resulting rows after the transformation would be like

```
2 198 39 309
2 194 73 73
2 190 55 55
2 190 55 63
2 190 55 70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this with `data.table`. Use `strsplit` to separate the values in `t_IDs` by spaces, and with `unlist` will have a long vector for the new `t_IDs` column. This is done for each `State` and `AgentID` combination.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)

dt[, list(t_IDs = unlist(strsplit(t_IDs, " "))), by = c("State", "AgentID")]
```

An alternative that does not assume uniqueness of `State`/`AgentID` might be:

```
dt[ ,.(State, AgentID, new_tIDs = unlist(strsplit(t_IDs, " "))), by = seq_len(nrow(dt))]
```

**Output**

```
     State AgentID t_IDs
  1:    56       1     1
  2:    56       1    15
  3:    81       2     2
  4:   126       3     3
  5:   161       4     4
 ---                    
112:   132      77    77
113:   160      78    78
114:    58      79    37
115:    58      79    79
116:    12      80    80
```

Comment: This may fail if `State`+`AgentID` are not all unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. Is there a way to do the assignment to `t_IDs` via `:=`? Because right now `t_IDs` is a temporary variable

Comment: @r2evans Correct, I agree, this assumed uniqueness of State/AgentID. I will add an alternative solution without this assumption...

Comment: No, I mean I don't want to create a new data table. I simply want to use the data.table (the actual dataset I'm using is huge)

Answer (score 2):

If the `State`/`AgendID` pairs are not guaranteed to be unique, one way to do this is with a row-wise unlisting:

```r
DT[, .(State = State[1], AgentID = AgentID[1], t_IDs = unlist(strsplit(t_IDs, split=" "))), by = seq_len(nrow(DT))][,-1]
#      State AgentID  t_IDs
#      <int>   <int> <char>
#   1:    56       1      1
#   2:    56       1     15
#   3:    81       2      2
#   4:   126       3      3
#   5:   161       4      4
#   6:   120       5      5
#   7:   120       5     52
#   8:   120       5     76
#   9:   138       6      6
#  10:    71       7      7
#  ---                     
# 107:   172      75     75
# 108:   120      76      5
# 109:   120      76     52
# 110:   120      76     76
# 111:   132      77     29
# 112:   132      77     77
# 113:   160      78     78
# 114:    58      79     37
# 115:    58      79     79
# 116:    12      80     80
```

Alternative, we can work with a list-column and then use `tidyr::unnest` to break it out:

```r
tidyr::unnest(DT[, t_IDs := strsplit(t_IDs, split=" ")][], t_IDs)
# # A tibble: 116 x 3
#    State AgentID t_IDs
#    <int>   <int> <chr>
#  1    56       1 1    
#  2    56       1 15   
#  3    81       2 2    
#  4   126       3 3    
#  5   161       4 4    
#  6   120       5 5    
#  7   120       5 52   
#  8   120       5 76   
#  9   138       6 6    
# 10    71       7 7    
# # ... with 106 more rows
```

(This has the side-effect of converting to `tbl_df`.)

Comment: When doing the assignment `t_IDs = unlist`, is there a way to make a direct assignment with `:=`?

Comment: Why is that important?

Comment: Because I have a huge dataset and don't want to copy the data everytime

Comment: When you choose to split a delimited field into multiple rows, you are losing most (all?) of the referential-semantics of `data.table`. There's no way to replace 1 cell of `t_IDs` with three cells of it in an in-place operation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data you provided (3 columns) i performed this:

```
n = matrix(ncol= 3)[-1,]
for(i in grep(' ', df$t_IDs)){
  b = df[i,]
  c = length(gregexpr(' ',as.character(b[,3]))[[1]])+1
  d = b[rep(1,c),1:2]
  d$t_IDs = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(b[1,3]), ' ')))
  n = rbind(n,as.matrix(d))
  }
df_new = df[-grep(' ', df$t_IDs),]
df_new = rbind(df_new, n)
df_new= df_new[order(df_new$AgentID),]
```

it gives this result

```
     State AgentID t_IDs
  1:    56       1     1
  2:    56       1    15
  3:    81       2     2
  4:   126       3     3
  5:   161       4     4
 ---                    
112:   132      77    77
113:   160      78    78
114:    58      79    37
115:    58      79    79
116:    12      80    80
```

I hope it helped

Comment: Many thanks for an answer, but could you explain a bit what you are doing?

Comment: Sure!
Basically I looked for all the rows in which df$t_IDs contains a ' ' (space) which mean there is several value in this row, then I duplicate these row to the number of element in the t_IDs, and bind them with the separated t_IDs. I do this to all the rows with need to be duplicated and then I replace the old rows (indentified with grep), with the one I have created (n object) and re order eveything

Comment: In brief: selection of the row with several values--> duplication of these row and bind them into the n objet --> elimination of the old rows (df[-grep(...),] --> replacement by the new ones

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy to do in `tidyr` -one-step solution

```
separate_rows(dt, t_IDs, sep = ' ')

# A tibble: 116 x 3
   State AgentID t_IDs
   <int>   <int> <chr>
 1    56       1 1    
 2    56       1 15   
 3    81       2 2    
 4   126       3 3    
 5   161       4 4    
 6   120       5 5    
 7   120       5 52   
 8   120       5 76   
 9   138       6 6    
10    71       7 7    
# ... with 106 more rows
```